# ssh with Python: How to get it right with escapes and quotes

Tags: python, ssh, escaping, quotes

I try to send some SSH commands from Python. It works pretty well, but I get a mess as soon as I have nested quotes.

So in the very basic situation I just do:

```
cmd = "ssh -A -t me@host \"do_on_host\"")) # notice the escaped quotes
Popen(cmd, ..., shell=True)
```

Now, in a more complicated situation, I'd like to use a user-specified command. Notice that I escaped the quotes around the user command and in the user command:

```
user_cmd = "prog -arg \"a string arg\""
cmd = "ssh -A -t me@host \"do_on_host; " + user_cmd + "\"")) # notice the escaped quotes
Popen(cmd, ..., shell=True)
```

It gets even worse when I try to ssh over two hops. Notice that I tried something with single and double quotes additional to the escaping:

```
user_cmd = "prog -arg \"a string arg\""
cmd = "ssh -A -t me@hop1 \"ssh -A -t me@hop2 '" + user_cmd + "'  \""
Popen(cmd, ..., shell=True)
```

It could get even worse: The snippets might be used in a script `do_over_ssh.py` where the `user_cmd` might be read with `argparse` from the console, like:

```
$ ./do_over_ssh.py my_cmd -arg "a string arg"
```

After all, I'm completely confused.

**What's the canonical and clean way to deal with nested quotes in Python 3.5?**

(Important notice: Other answers are for Python 2.7!)

Comment: why not use Fabric3 to run remote user commands? multihop also works as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658874/how-to-do-multihop-ssh-with-fabric

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a doc string to simplify this. Try using three quotes around what you're sending:

```
'''Stuff goes here and "literally translates all of the contents automatically"'''
```

For the line:

```
cmd = "ssh -A -t me@hop1 \"ssh -A -t me@hop2 '" + user_cmd + "'  \""
```

It would be simpler to use format:

```
cmd = '''ssh -A -t me@hop1 "ssh -A me@hop2 {}"'''.format(user_cmd)
```

Comment: The backslash before the `''' on the last line, is that a typo or what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

May be not the canonical way you are expecting but if I had such issues, I'd try to build my own quoting engine, something along the lines of

```
import re

def _quote(s):
    return re.sub(r'[\"\'\\]', lambda match: "\\" + match.group(0), s)

def wquote(s):
    return '"{}"'.format(_quote(s))

def quote(s):
    return "'{}'".format(_quote(s))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    com = 'prog -arg {}'.format(wquote("a string arg"))
    print(com)
    com = "ssh -A -t me@hop2 {}".format(wquote(com))
    print(com)
    com = "ssh -A -t me@hop1 {}".format(wquote(com))
    print(com)

""" --> my output

prog -arg "a string arg"
ssh -A -t me@hop2 "prog -arg \"a string arg\""
ssh -A -t me@hop1 "ssh -A -t me@hop2 \"prog -arg \\\"a string arg\\\"\""
"""
```